# How to get only class name without namespace

Tags: ruby, namespaces

There is a class like this.

```
module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end
```

And I want to get the class name of `Bar` without `Foo`.

```
bar = Foo::Bar.new
bar.class.to_s.match('::(.+)$'){ $1 }
```

I could get the class name by this code, but I don't think this is a best way to get it.

Is there better way to get the name of class without namespace?

Comment: _Sidenote_: your regexp will produce wrong result on `Foo::Bar::Baz` and any class having two and more nesting level.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The canonical way to do this is to invoke [Object#class](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-class) and [Module#name](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-name). For example:

```
bar.class.name.split('::').last
#=> "Bar"
```

Answer (score 166):

If you are using ActiveSupport (part of Rails), you can actually use the `#demodulize` method on the `String` class.
http://apidock.com/rails/String/demodulize

```
bar.class.name.demodulize
```

Comment: Right! But you don't need Rails completely. You only need the `activesupport` gem, so you can use that in other projects as well.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this would work fine too:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
  end
end

bar = Foo::Bar.new

print bar.class.to_s.split('::').last
```

This would result in

```
Bar
```

I also believe it would be a bit faster than the regular expression evaluation, but I'm not sure about this and I haven't performed a benchmark.